# R: Why my vector is disordered?

Tags: r, vector, zoo

Let say I have this zoo vector

```
mine <- zoo(c(rep(0,4),rep(1,4),rep(0,5),rep(1,23),rep(0,4),rep(1,2)),as.chron(seq(1:42)))
```

And I want to extract several elements in some order

```
> mine[14]
01/15/70 
       1 
> mine[5]
01/06/70 
       1 
> mine[41]
02/11/70 
       1
```

It works!.
But now I try to do it in a different way

```
zz <- c(14, 5, 41)
mine[zz]

01/06/70 01/15/70 02/11/70 
       1        1        1
```

I don't know why I get it in a different order.
How can I keep the order I want, the order of my list ??
I don't mind if it's a list, a vector, by columns or by row, but I'd like to get it in the order I've asked for.

cheers

Comment: please try to provide reproducible code, this example requires the zoo package and chron package in R, of unspecified version on an unstated environment

Comment: Use `rep`'s `each` argument to avoid repeaded calls to it, e.g., `rep(rep.int(0:1, 3), each = c(4, 4, 5, 23, 4, 2))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to why zoo does this is that it has a method for the function `[` (`[.zoo`), and it creates a new zoo object from the subsetted values, which it logically wants to reorder so that it is a valid zoo object.

You can achieve what you want by accessing the time indices and data via the relevant accessor functions:

```
> index(mine)[c(14, 5, 41)]
[1] 01/15/70 01/06/70 02/11/70
> coredata(mine)[c(14, 5, 41)]
[1] 1 1 1
```

If you want to combine this into a single step, write your own fun to do:

```
myExtract <- function(x, want) {
    out <- coredata(mine)[want]
    names(out) <- index(x)[want]
    out
}
```

Which gives:

```
> myExtract(mine, want = c(14, 5, 41))
01/15/70 01/06/70 02/11/70 
       1        1        1
```

Comment: Thank You very much. Simple (but important) things like these makes a code fail